# wkhtmtopdf javascript not working

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf

I want to execute javascript code before exporting to pdf. When I execute the code on Ubuntu, its working fine but on CentOS , javascript is running when the page is being previewed in the broswer,but doesn't run when i download the PDF file (on the server).

I am also using 'javascript-delay': "15000".
But it doesn't work.

I am using the following version of the library in my local system (Ubuntu 16.10). Using this version, I am able to generate proper PDF file.

> wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2

But for centos, the javascript is not being executed before PDF export.
The following version is available:

> wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)